# Function overloading

Tags: c++

I found this code , and i m not sure that whether overloading should happen or not.

```
void print( int (*arr)[6], int size );

void print( int (*arr)[5], int size );
```

what happens if I pass pointer to an array of 4 elements , to it should come...

any thread will be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Overloading will happen, and passing the pointer to the array of 4 `int`'s will not match either function. It's clearer if you write them as the equivalent form:

```
void print( int arr[][6], int size );
void print( int arr[][5], int size );
```

An N×4 array can be decayed to a pointer to array of 4 `int`'s. And it's well known that 2D arrays having different 2nd dimensions are incompatible.

Answer (score 6):

[KennyTM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590599/2590615#2590615) is the correct one. Here's an additional thought, though, based on the fact that your question comes with a `C++` tag. In C++, you can use templates with non-type arguments to find out array dimensions:

```
#include <iostream>

template< std::size_t N >
void print(int (&arr)[N]) {std::cout << N << '\n';}

int main()
{
    int arr[6];
    print(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right, of course. I overlooked the `*`. I should pay more attention.

Answer (score 1):

The call would be ambiguous as none of the two overloads would be able to convert to `int (*arr)[4]`. You need to pass in an element of 5 or 6 elements explicitly.

VS2008 gives:

```
error C2665: 'print' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
(2088): could be 'void print(int (*)[5],int)'
(2093): or       'void print(int (*)[6],int)'
 while trying to match the argument list '(int (*)[4], int)'
```

Hope that helps.